# Retrieve Code or Page From Previous Version of Managed Package

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

How can I obtain a version of an Apex class from a previous version of my managed package? I accidentally overwrote the code in Salesforce with an older local copy.

Comment: Go back in time and start using a version control system.  Then buy past you a beer for not causing future you a bunch of headaches.  Seriously, though, start using version control.

Comment: Version control is vital (and I do use it) — the reason I got caught it is 99% of the time I'm the only one touching the code. My business partner edited a class and I subsequently overwrote it because there's no warning in Maven's Mate when you try to do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new patch organisation for the package inside the development org for the version of the package desired. Once you've been emailed the new user login credentials you can then login to the new org, open up the developer console and retrieve the lost code.